# PHP mail() - HTML shows up as an attachment once a file attachment is added

Tags: php, html, email-client

Had finally gotten all the bugs out of this and now they said "Oh, we'll need to add attachments..."  So, this sends an html mail with a plaintext version and was doing just swell.  Now that I have the attachments arriving the mail clients are showing the plaintext version inline and the html version as another attachment and then a seemingly empty 93 byte file with a name like ATT00248.txt.

Can anyone either bash me over the head from behind or tell me where I am going wrong?  I want the HTML inline where available in the mail user interface, the plain text version where HTML is not available, and the single attachment as an attachment.

Any help?

```
<?php
$template = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/leads/templates/'.$_SESSION['templateFile'];
ob_start();
include($template);
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if (strlen($html) == 0) {
    echo "The template at $template did not load.";
    exit;
}

$email   = $_SESSION['user']->email;
$name    = $_SESSION['user']->first_name . ' ' . $_SESSION['user']->last_name;
$from = "$name <$email>";
$subject = unslash($_SESSION['subject']);

$TextMessage =  strip_tags(unslash($_SESSION['message']));

$notice_text = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.";
$plain_text =  str_replace('&nbsp;',' ', $TextMessage);

if ($_SESSION['attachment']) {
    $fileatt = 'files/' . $_SESSION['attachment'];
    $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
    $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $mailtype = 'mixed';

    $fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; 
    $fileatt_name = $_SESSION['attachment'];
} else {
    $mailtype = 'alternative';
}

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_$semi_rand";
$mime_boundary_header = chr(34) . $mime_boundary . chr(34);

$body = "$notice_text

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$plain_text

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$html

--$mime_boundary
";

$body .= "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"--$mime_boundary\n";



// #1  //
if ($to = $_SESSION['recipients'][0]) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header);

    echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($to) . ".<br />";
}


// #2  //
if ($to = $_SESSION['recipients'][1]) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header);
    echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($to) . ".<br />";
}

// #3  //
if ($to = $_SESSION['recipients'][2]) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header);
    echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($to) . ".<br />";
}

// #4  //
if ($to = $_SESSION['recipients'][3]) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header);
    echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($to) . ".<br />";
}

// #5 //
if ($to = $_SESSION['recipients'][4]) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header);
    echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($to) . ".<br />";
}

// CC self?  //
if ($_SESSION['cc_me']) {
    mail($from, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header);
    echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($from) . ".<br />";
}

if ($fileatt) {
    unlink($fileatt);
}

echo "<a href='email_start.php'>Click here</a> to send another email.";
list($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['subject'], $_SESSION['bullets'], $_SESSION['message'], 
    $_SESSION['templateFile'], $_SESSION['template'], $_SESSION['cc_me'], $_SESSION['recipients']) = '';
?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a ready-made mailer class like Swiftmailer? http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Pekka- thank you!  I get so into rolling my6 own I cause myself stress sometimes!  swiftmailer made the job simple and stressfree.  Thank you!!!  You should add this as an answer and I'll select it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pekka had it right - It was simple and robust to use Swiftmailer. http://swiftmailer.org

Answer (score 0):

I'd post this as a comment, but it's too long.

```
// #1  //
if ($to = $_SESSION['recipients'][0]) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header);

    echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($to) . ".<br />";
}


// #2  ... #3 ... #4 ... #5
```

Will end up executing all blocks, since `($to = $_SESSION['recipients'][0])` will be always true. It will also display the "Email sent to ..." even when `mail()` fails.

What you want is:

```
if (in_array($to, $_SESSION['recipients'])) {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header)) {
        echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($to) . ".<br />";
    }
}
```

Or, if you really want to mail everyone, or

```
foreach ($_SESSION['recipients'] as $to ) {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/$mailtype;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header)) {
        echo "Email sent to " . htmlentities($to) . ".<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I should have posted a link to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419858/php-mail-sends-empty-content-when-looping-over-array-of-addresses

As an explanation of why I iterated the way I did.

Comment: Headers should be separated with "\r\n". This is part of smtp standard and NOT OPTIONAL. rfc 5321: 2.3.8. Lines